# How to Submit a Form With Action Page in a Different Folder?

Tags: php

I am not been able to submit a form if its action is on a page in a  different folder. I tried the following code:

```
<form action="model/insert_resident.php" onsubmit="return formvalidate()" method="POST">

    <label for="name">Name:</label><span id="err_name" style="color:red; display: none;">Enter Name</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    

    <label for="flatid">Flat Id:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="flatid" name="flatid">

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">

    <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
      <input type="number" id="phone" class="form-control"  name="phone">
      <input type="hidden" id="date" class="form-control" name="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>">


    
     <p id="chk"> </p> 

     <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  onClick="formvalidate()" name="insert" value="Add">

     
   </form>
```

Comment: Where is your `<form>` element? You need to correctly specify the action URL in the `action` attribute.

Comment: Can you add the javascript, `formvalidate` function? Without that function the form will submit to whatever is designated in the form `action` so if the form is **not** submitting it suggests that the function is preventing it somehow?!

Answer (score 0):

As you have given us following in the form tag:

```
action="model/insert_resident.php
```

we assume that your file called insert_resident.php is in the sub-directory model. Have you tried opening this page with the direct URL in the browser?
You should also try to prefix with a / or ./ to mean current directory.

```
action="./model/insert_resident.php
```

Comment: But, I have specified the path...action="model/insert_resident.php"